# How to use linkWithCredential with verifyPhoneNumber?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

1. I create a Firebase Auth user with an email and password
2. User logs in
3. User decides to add a phone number to their profile
4. I call `verifyPhoneNumber` with an intent to receive a code, call `PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(...)` and link resulting `AuthCredential` to the email and password.
5. Instead, Android auto retrieves the code, user automatically sign-ins with phone number, their UID changes (it's a new user) and there's no way to link phone credentials back to the original email/password user. To perform a successful link I need to see the SMS code, which is nowhere to be found in case of successful auto sign-in.
6. ????
7. NO PROFIT.

Any ideas? I tried to set the timeout to 0 for `verifyPhoneNumber` but auto login still works. Accepting defeat and just link `EmailAndPassword` credentials to phone number instead of vice versa is not an option, because it will require a massive copying of data from old user record into new, changing all references to this UID everywhere, etc.

Answer (score 3):

`verifyPhoneNumber` resolves with a `PhoneAuthCredential`.

It doesn't matter whether the code is auto-retrieved or instant validation occurs. A `PhoneAuthCredential` is outputted on `verifyPhoneNumber` completion.

That credential can either be used to `signInWithCredential` for sign-in or to link to an existing user via `linkWithCredential`.

Comment: Good catch that `verifyPhoneNumber` already gives me the `AuthCredential` and no need to call `getCredential()` but the main question remains unanswered: how to prevent the auto login and thus change of the `currentUser`.

Comment: What do you mean by auto login? Do you mean instant phone auth validation?

Comment: Yes, instant validation immediately logs a (new) user in.

Comment: That is not correct. Instant validation will trigger the `onVerificationCompleted` callback with the `PhoneAuthCredential` as documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#verification-callbacks

Comment: Well, I also consider this incorrect behaviour, but this is what it does and it's documented right in the official doc: `Either sends an SMS with a 6 digit code to the phone number specified, or sign's the user in and verificationCompleted is called.` https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/verifyPhoneNumber.html

Comment: There's probably some logic behind this, but it totally escapes me. Probabilistic sign-in: you call a function and it *may* sign you in, but you never know.

Comment: Hmm, it appears you are using the Flutter SDK. I just realized this. I am not sure if this is incorrectly documented, or whether they wrapped it incorrectly. (it actually uses the official Android SDK under the hood). Try opening a ticket about the mismatch on their GitHub repo.